# C++ Confusing scope of redeclared variables in for loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, scope, redeclaration

The following while loop does not terminate. This is because the variable `x` is being re-declared inside the while loop. But I don't understand why in the second iteration onward, the statements `x<10` and `y=x` considers the x defined in the outer scope and not the `x` defined in the block scope in the following statement.
Is this because once the first iteration ends, the `x` defined in the block scope is destroyed and the loop begins to execute fresh?

```
#include<iostream>
int main () {
  int x = 0, y;  
  while(x <10 ){
    y = x;
    std::cout<<"y is :"<< y <<std::endl;  
    int x = y + 1;
    std::cout<<"x is :"<< x <<std::endl;  
  }
  std::cout<<"While loop is over"<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every iteration the while loop evaluates the outer scope `x` and `y` is assigned the value of the outer scope `x`. After that another `x` is defined in the inner scope which is what the second `std::cout` uses, but the program makes no other use of the inner `x`

In the code below I replaced the inner `x` with `z` but otherwise the behavior is identical. The only difference is that there is not a second `x` within a more inner scope to hide the outer one:

```
#include<iostream>

int main () {
    int x = 0, y;
    while(x <10 ){
        y = x;
        std::cout<<"y is :"<< y <<std::endl;
        int z = y + 1;
        std::cout<<"z is :"<< z <<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"While loop is over"<<std::endl;
}
```

Below I have an example that is intended to clear the confusion. In the inner scope `x` is not being "re-declared", a new `x` is being declared and it goes out of scope after the `}`:

```
#include<iostream>

int main () {
    int x = 1;
    {
        int x = 2;
        std::cout << x << '\n'; // 2
    }
    std::cout << x << '\n'; // 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you understand it correctly. So every time when compare in `while`, it is using the outer `x`.

```
while (x < 10) {
    y = x; //Here the x is the outer one. The inner one does not exist yet.
    std::cout << "y is :" << y << std::endl;  
    int x = y + 1; // From here, x will refer to the inner one.
    std::cout << "x is :" << x << std::endl;  
    // inner x is destroyed.
}
```